# Are there functions $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with $0\in D$, indefinitelly differentiable in $0$ and such that for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f^{(n)}(0)=n$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives

Are there functions $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with $0\in D$, indefinitelly differentiable in $0$ and such that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f^{(n)}(0)=n$?. I have thought about holomorphic functions, but this case is excluded by the range of our function. Now, if I take a sequence of real numbers such that $f^{k}(0)=x_k$, I get that $x_n=n$ and $f^n(0)=(f^{n-1}(0))'=n$ and $f^{n-1}(0)=n-1=x_{n-1}$ and such $x_{n-1}=n-1$. Then, for a real $x$, $f^{n-1}(x)=\int f^{n}(x)$ and $\int f^{n}(x)=F(x)$ and so $F(0)=0=n-1\rightarrow n=1$ and this is a contradiction. I have a feeling that this is incomplete as I don't think I can integrate the expressions like that but it is the only ideea I have.Any help?

Comment: Hint: Use a Taylor series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first assume that such a function $f$ exists, and that $f$ can be developed into a Taylor series at $x=0$. Then
$$
 f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{n!} x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}  = x e^x \, .
$$
So we have a possible candidate: $f(x) = xe^x$ is indeed infinitely differentiable on $\Bbb R$ and equal to its Taylor series. That justifies the above calculations and shows that $f^{(n)}(0) = n$ holds for all $n$.

It is also straightforward to verify that
$$
 f^{(n)}(x) = (x+n)e^x \, .
$$

We can even extend the domain to the complex numbers: $f(z) = ze^z$ is an entire function.

Comment: Thank you, Martin!!!!